# PHP is Counting Some Characters as 3 Characters

Tags: php, string, utf-8, special-characters

I am trying to insert text in between special characters, but the problem is that php interprets some special characters as 3 characters for some unknown reason.  For example if you were to use `strlen()` on any of the following symbols, it would return 3:

```
➊➜❚✶➪
```

Therefore, I need a way to figure out how to add something in between each special character of a string.  For example, if the string were:

```
TE➊➜❚S✶T➪
```

The *ideal* output would be:

```
|T|E|➊|➜|❚|S|✶|T|➪|
```

I have tried using this:

```
<?php
$string = 'TE➊➜❚S✶T➪';
$array = str_split($string);
foreach ($array as $char) {
    $newstring .= '|'.$char;
}
$newstring .= '|';
echo $newstring;
?>
```

However, since php interprets the special characters as 3 characters, it inserts the tag in between each single character of the three-character symbol which causes the output appear like this:

```
|T|E|â|ž|Š|â|ž|œ|â||š|S|â|œ|¶|T|â|ž|ª|
```

Therefore it is changing the symbols like this:

```
➊ => âžŠ
➜ => âžœ
❚ => âš
✶ => âœ¶
➪ => âžª
```

And setting each single character as an element of the array.

**Question**: *Is there any way to count such symbols as one character when splitting a string per character in order to insert something in between?*

What I have tried:

1. Encoding in UTF-8
2. Encoding in UTF-8 without BOM
3. Using `htmlspecialchars()`
4. Using `htmlspecialchars_decode()`
5. Using `htmlentities()`
6. Using `html_entity_decode()`

All of which made absolutely no change.

Is there any way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Tip: functions that start with `html...` are designed to deal with HTML. If you have encoding issues with plain text, they'll almost never help.

Comment: The page as a whole deals with HTML.  It takes a user input and does some php stuff on it, then outputs the new text.

Comment: I honestly think that converting `<CITE>` to `<CI|T|E|>` will break your app.

Comment: The website is not in actuality adding a `|` in between each character.  The real result I needed was an array of the characters in order to do a comparison.  This example just made it easier to understand the problem.  Also, I just tried `<CITE>` and it worked perfectly, but I don't see why that should break it.

Comment: Never mind... I see people all the time corrupting their input data with random functions they don't really understand (`addslashes()` and `strip_tags()` are among the most popular). I just wanted to prevent you against that. I'm sorry my explanations weren't good enough.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  I think you thought that I was using `htmlspecialchars()` **before** separating each letter.  I use it after to prevent making the possible `&|a|m|p|;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) works with single-byte strings only. If you need to split a multibyte string, use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) with the `u` modifier.

Replace

```
$array = str_split($string);
```

with

```
$array = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: This works perfectly but would you mind providing an explanation as to why it works?

Comment: => `/u` => utf-8 mode => that understands multibytes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`mbstring`](https://www.php.net/mbstring) functions, tell it you are using UTF-8. Also, `htmlspecialchars()` and the like have a charset argument: if you're not using ISO-8859-1, and your PHP version is lower then 5.4, you MUST set it to the correct one.

Comment: Yes, I am using UTF-8 and doesn't `htmlspecialchars()` default to UTF-8?

Comment: Well, it depends on your version I see now: _"If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards."_  I for one am glad the default has been changed, but most people I know are still on 5.3. What version are you using? Didn't know the default changed BTW, so thank you for making me check ;)

Comment: Oh, it is 5.2.17.  I see.

Comment: I know this may be discouraged to say here for some reason... but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that is missing is joining the array into the appropriate string you like. So you can make this change to get your desired string.

```
$array = preg_split('//u', $s);
print_r($array);
$ss = implode('|', $array);
```

Comment: Thank you but this is what the `foreach` in the original code in the question was meant for.  The problem was that one character was being broken up into three.